# Replace non-word characters, except at end

Tags: regex

I'm sure a question like this has been asked before, but I can't figure out the search parameters to find the answer. I'm trying to replace non-word characters (or multiple non-words in a row), but not those occurring at the end of the string. For example, the following:

`Corynebacterium sp JB4.`, `Arthrobacter arilaitensis re117, CIP 108037` and `Microbacterium sp. JB110`

should become:

`Corynebacterium_sp_JB4`, `Arthrobacter_arilaitensis_re117_CIP_108037` and `Microbacterium_sp_JB110`

After trying to figure out a way to not select the final period in the first item, I realized that I actually need 2 operations anyway, one to replace trailing non-word characters with an empty string, and a different one to replace the other characters with `"_"`, so the following does works in python:

`re.sub(r'\W+', "_", re.sub(r'\W$', "", string))`

But I'm left wondering, would there be a way to do this if I wanted the first item to end as `Corynebacterium_sp_JB4.`? I played around with a couple of different things on http://www.regexr.com/ but I couldn't find a solution. Thought it might have something to do with look-ahead, but (?!$) doesn't seem to work (or maybe I'm doing it wrong, I haven't used look-ahead options before).

Comment: If you want, you may use Notepad++: `(?<o1>[^\r\n\w]+$)|(?<o2>[^\r\n\w]+)` and replace with `(?{o1}:_)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggested regex for your case:

```
/(\s|\W)(?=.*.)/g
```

#### Explanation by parts:

1. (\s|\W) - Search for any whitespace (`\s`) OR "not word" elements (`\W`)
2. (?=.*.) - That are followed by something

#### Regexr results

[image: Regexr example of this case]

Comment: Apologies for marking as correct over a year after the initial answer. I can't remember precisely, but I think I got excited that this worked and continued with the project :-). Better late than never I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

> would there be a way to do this if I wanted the first item to end as
>   `Corynebacterium_sp_JB4.`?

A simpler way is

```
re.sub(r'\W+\b', '_', 'Corynebacterium sp JB4.')
```

- the `\b` causes only the non-word characters which are followed by a word to be matched.